# How to pass NDB data to task queue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, task-queue, payload

Here is the entity I would like to pass to the task:

```
class MyData(ndb.Model):
    ...
    text = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    data = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)
    details = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Details)
```

Can I do something like below?

```
mydata = MyData.query()
mydata = mydata.filter(...)
mydata = mydata.order(MyData.added)
mydata = mydata.fetch(100)
for d in mydata:
  taskqueue.add(url='/worker', payload=d)
```

How can I extract the data from the payload then? Don't think that `self.request.get('payload')` will work.
Understand that I can pass just the ndb key and read the entity within the task. But it will require additional read operations. Or, can I use `keys_only` somehow when `fetch(100)`? `keys_only` operations are free in accordance with [the doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing):

> Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or
>   keys-only queries, and these operations are free.

But are they counted as datastore read operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a `keys_only` Query (as you mentioned, this should incur little to no charge), and I would update your taskqueue to add in a single batch call.

```py
mydata = MyData.query()
mydata = mydata.filter(...)
# the order shouldn't matter, unless you want to make sure that property exists.
# mydata = mydata.order(MyData.added)   
mydata = mydata.fetch(100, keys_only=True)
tasks = [taskqueue.Task(url='/worker', params={'key': key.urlsafe()}) for key in mydata]
taskqueue.Queue('default').add(tasks)
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the advantage of single batch call? I am planning to use unique name for each task (so, I will not have duplicate processing of the same error), what will happen with batch call if there is a task with duplicate name?

Comment: Could you please also help to understand how to extract payload? `self.request.get('payload')` is empty.

Comment: Updated the ``payload`` to ``params`` - with the way it is now you'll use ``self.request.get('key')``.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues#Queue_add describes what happens when you add tasks that already exist. If you are worried about duplicate tasks per item, I'd add them one at a time and catch ``(taskqueue.TaskAlreadyExistsError, taskqueue.TombstonedTaskError)``

Comment: Ah, yes, I know how to use `params`, but was interested especially in `payload` ;)

Comment: You can retrieve the ``payload`` from ``self.request.body`` in the task handler. :)  (payload is the POST data)

Comment: Could you please post the code? The idea is clear, but I don't understand how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

`d` is still an ndb object.  To pass that as a dictionary, try this (untested):

```
taskqueue.add(url='/worker', payload=d.to_dict())
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict

Comment: This will not work as ``details`` is an ndb.KeyProperty, which is not JSON encodable without some additional work. I'd override ``to_dict`` to handle KeyProperty and make sure to apply ``.urlsafe()`` to convert them to strings. Then, you'll have no problem fetching those entities later.